# change default indention in Javascript-IDE spacemacs

Tags: javascript, emacs

I've already searched a lot about this, and tried them out, none of these works:

`(setq js-indent-level 2)
  (setq js2-indent-level 2)
  (setq jsx-indent-level 2)
  (setq Javascript-indent-level 2)`

Here's my spaceemacs file:

https://gist.github.com/Bersam/e54c9b8d892c69077303

Answer (score 6):

I've got the answer in gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs we need to change 'js2-basic-offset' variable.

`(setq js2-basic-offset 2)`

Comment: ```SPC h d v``` would give you all valid variables.